# How to redefine a type with a new generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

There are a lot of functions in libraries.
In this case, I pick `useQuery` from `blitz`.

typescript `Parameters` returns the type of parameters.
So, `Parameters<typeof useQuery>` returns a type like

```
<T extends QueryFn, TResult = PromiseType<ReturnType<T>>>(queryFn: T, params: FirstParam<T>, options?: QueryOptions<TResult, Error> | undefined) => [...]
```

In my case, I would like to redefine a new parameter with that type.
e.g)

```
  type T = Parameters<typeof useQuery>[2]
```

However, `T` is defined as `QueryOptions<unknown, Error>` because `TResult` is unknown.

How can I pass a type to `T`?

Expected result is to pass a type instead of `unknown`. Like,

```
  let opt: ??? // the type is QueryOptions<any, Error>
```

Thanks for your kind helps.

Comment: DO you want to redeclare function type or only type of function parameter?

Comment: I would like to redeclare the type of function parameter in this case.
It may be useful that the case a library never export the type of function parameter.

However, if I could redeclare function type, I may get the function type by using `Parameters<typeof new function>`

Answer (score 1):

Now possible in TS 4.7+ with [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions)!

```
type T = Parameters<typeof useQuery<SomeType>>[2]
```

You are now allowed to pass generic parameters to functions without calling them! See attached release notes for more things you can do with this.